# What are best practices for kubernetes geo distributed cluster?

Tags: kubernetes

What is the best practice to get Geo distributed cluster with asynchronous network channels ?

I suspect I would need to have some "load balancer" which should redirect connections "within" it's own DC, do you know anything like this already in place?

Second question, should we use one HA cluster or create dedicated cluster for each of the DC ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption of the kubernetes development team is that cross-cluster federation will be the best way to handle cross-zone workloads.  The tooling for this is easy to imagine, but has not emerged yet.  You can (on your own) set up regional or global load-balancers and direct traffic to different clusters based on things like GeoIP.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Byzantine Clients. My team is currently working on a solution for erasure coded storage in asynchronous network that prevents some problems caused by faulty clients, but it relies on correct clients to establish a consistent state across the servers.

The network consists of a set of servers {P1, ...., Pn} and a set of clients {C1, ..., Cn}, which are all PTIM with running time bounded by a polynomial in a given securty parameter. Servers and clients together are parties. Theres an adversary, which is a PITM with running time boundded by a polynoil. Servers nd clients are controlled by adversary. In this case, theyre calld *corruptd*, othrwise, theyre called *honest*. An adversary that contrls up to *t* servers is called *t-limited*.

If protecting innocent clients from getting inconsistent values is a priority, then you should go ne, but from the pointview of a client, problems caused by faulty clients don't really hurt the system.

Comment: thanks for the answer, is there any solution available? You team is working on "proprietary" solution or I can find it on github for evaluation?

Comment: It's proprietary. I was hoping my answer'd tell you a general direction to move in, at the very least.